# PHP with OOP and MVC

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, class

Using PHP 5.x

Question, lets say I want to display results from a database. Lets say the last 30 stories from the database. Using OOP and MVC would the ideal setup be you have a class that connects to the db, a class that queries the database to get the information then a class that handles the display of the results and then a page that puts it all together?

So basically I would pass the db connection object to the class that gets me the story results from the database Then pass the story class object to the display class to build the view then pass that back to the view itself and echo out the value? Hopefully this makes sense, just trying to see if Im understanding this:

dbconnect_class.php

storyresults_class.php

storydisplay_class.php

Include all 3 into a page such as display_stories.php, which I believe is the controller in mvc, then run the code and display it in the view which would be in its basic form an include to a template file.

Comment: Thats a bit too broad I guess. Have a look at the various frameworks and how they implement these things. You will find that they do it similar but then again different.

Comment: Agreed - not answerable here.  Do some reading and look at existing frameworks, here's a good start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller#PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC meaning Model -> View -> Controller. In most of the frameworks the request comes to the Controller, the Controller asks the Model to retrieve the database results then the same Controller sends the results to the view in order to display them so that's the basic breakdown of a MVC application.

Comment: I guess my next question is, is it recommended to pass the data you received from the model to a view class or just pass it to the view/html file and have php inside the view with say a foreach loop to loop through the results?

Comment: Most of the frameworks provide templating languages such as jinja or smarty which are capable enough to manipulate the incoming data as needed, however, most of the application logic should stay inside the controller while the view should only do basic stuff such as a foreach loop how you say. Anything else should be prepared by the controller before being passed onto the view file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the results object around. That will mean the display class needs to know the implementation within that class.

What you can do is let the controller get the results then pass the results to the display class. 
You can make a data class that keeps the data in a suitable object which you can then pass to the display class.

However, this is just some general oop advice but for better mvc, you need to read on that. Some links have been provided by others.

Comment: So your saying in the controller call the data class that queries the db for what I want and returns the results from the database then pass the results given back from the data class into the display class and the display class would loop through the results and I display it however I want. Then pass back the end result from the display class back to the controller then pass that onto the view? Is that the basics of it?

Comment: usually, the view will be the last part of your logic. you pass it the data, then it processes it. it can then display it.you dont have to give the data back to the controller. the job of the controller is just to instruct the objects to do their jobs and coordinate the actions which occur in the script as well as determine what each object should do and pass info.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your using a template engine it would be very difficult to not write php code in a view file. At the company I work for, we have developed a set of UI components that allow us to bind data to a component in the controller and have that component render on the view, similary to how asp.net controls work.